# How to bind to a Service that was started by another instance of the application

Tags: android, android-service, background-process

I have a background `Service` that need to be running even if the application gets killed by Android. This is currently working perfectly.

My problem is that when I restart the application (with the background service still running), I want my `Activity` to bind to the service to have access to some of its methods. When I try to bind with a `ServiceConnection`, the `onServiceConnected` is never called.

```
final private ServiceConnection serviceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onServiceConnected");  //this is never called
        MyBackgroundService.ServiceBinder binder = (MyBackgroundService.ServiceBinder) service;
        backgroundService = binder.getService();
    }

    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onServiceDisconnected");
        backgroundService = null;
    }

};

private void bindBackgroundService(){
    this.bindService(new Intent(this, MyBackgroundService.class), serviceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
}
```

Am I doing this the wrong way? Is it better to stop the `Service` and restart it?

Comment: Did you unbind the `Service` before the `Activity` was destroyed?

Comment: "I have a background Service that need to be running even if the application gets killed by Android" -- if Android terminates the process hosting the service, the service goes away. The service might restart at some point, depending on what you are returning from `onStartCommand()`.

Comment: @Emmanuel I try, but the onDestroy is not often called...

Comment: @CommonsWare I use START_STICKY so it can still run after it lose its binding with my activity. But I found that there is a bug with KitKat that prevents START_STICKY to behave like it should, so I have an alarm broadcast receiver that restart it when it detects that it has been killed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the class that binded the background service is a singleton and my alarm broadcast receiver that is making sure the background service is always running instantiates this singleton, I had access to this singleton and I was trying to bind to the service that was already binded.